# I want to create orders in Magento2. Orders have bundled product

Tags: magento2, orders, bundled-product, save

I want to add orders in Magento 2. Orders have bundled products.Is there specific function/parameters we need to use to store bundled product orders ?

Comment: explain in more detail what you looking for.